# How can I specify the step size when retrieving data in DolphinDB?

Tags: range, dolphindb

How can I specify the step size when retrieving data in DolphinDB? For example, I want to extract numbers from 100 to 1000 with an interval of 100. Is there a similar method in DolphinDB to Python's `range` function where I can specify the *step* parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a user-defined function in DolphinDB, for example:

```
def rangePro(start, stop, step=1) {
        num = (stop - start) / step
        return start + (0..num) * step
}
rangePro(100, 1000, 100)
```